# CKEditor - set default font family

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg

Is there a way in CKEditor to set a default font?

What I mean is, i want to force the CKEditor to only use a particular font and no others.

I have the folloinwg so far:

```
CKEDITOR.inline( editable_533, {
   toolbar: [
     ['Bold','Italic','Underline'],
     ['NumberedList','BulletedList'],
     ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight'],
     ['Undo','Redo'],
     '/',
     ['TextColor','Font','FontSize']
   ],
   font_names: 'PT Sans/PT Sans',
   font_defaultLabel: 'PT Sans'
```

});

In the font drop down, i only have one font. There is some text in the CKEditor by default, but this isn't the correct font (PT Sans).

I don't want to hardcode this in the css as there are more than one CKEditor instance, which also need a single font (other than PT Sans).

Thanks

UPDATE:

I have tried adding the following:

```
      font_style:
      {
          element   : 'span',
          styles    : { 'font-family' : 'PT Sans' },
          overrides : [ { element : 'font', attributes : { 'face' : null } } ]
      },
```

But this doesn't change the font to PT Sans

Comment: Do you want to force it for eyecandy or to completely change the output of the editor?

Comment: Well there are 2 inline editors. One must be PT Sans, the other one must be Arial. But there could be multiple inline editors. They are created dynamically (font is stored in a DB) and thus must match the font pulled from the DB. This means I can't start hardcoding the `font-family` in the CSS as the `editable_NO` will always be different

Comment: Is this possible to do?